# Getting {object Object} in jquery JSON php

Tags: php, jquery, json, object

I'm trying to get two dates based on a selection from a previous dropdown.

Functionally, the process is working.  However, I am getting a result of {object Object} instead of the dates.

PHP

```
$data=array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $data[]=array('start_date'=>date("m/d/Y",strtotime($row['start_date'])));
    //log_msg(print_r($data, true));
}

echo (json_encode($data));
```

jQuery

```
 .ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'admin_workshop_update_retrieve.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'value=' + choice,
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            $("#workshop_dates").append($('<option value ="' + v + '" >' + v + '</option><br>'));
            });
        }
    });
```

It seems like I'm missing something easy to turn the JSON object into a string or text.  Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: print the value of `console.log(data)`

Comment: tip : use **JSON_FORCE_OBJECT** parameter with `json_encode`

Answer (score 4):

You should treat them as objects:

```
$("#workshop_dates").append($('<option value ="' + v.start_date + '" >' + v.start_date + '</option><br>'));
```

Comment: may i know what is the usage of **k** in `function(k,v)` ?

Comment: @diEcho - `data` seems to be an array of objects, so in this case `k` would be the numeric index of the current array element where `v` is the actual array element at that index. See the [`$.each()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Comment: `k` is the array index, eg: `0`, `1`